# What is the best way to pass handler variable from MainActivity class to background thread class in android kotlin?

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, android-progressbar, android-handler

I have two separated classes (separated by files). Classes are named MainActivity.kt and BackgroundThreadClass.kt. MainActivity class is actually an activity and BackgroundThreadClass is extended by Thread class and I simulate some long task in it.
When I press the Button thread is executed and my progress bar is updated.
This android application I made just for a better understanding of how the thread is working.

So I have a few questions about this:

1. From MainActivity.kt to BackgroundThreadClass.kt I passed the handler variable by the primary constructor in BackgroundThreadClass.kt and used it in the run() method to send message back to MainActivity.kt where I updated the progress bar.
   Is this right way to pass the handler variable by the primary constructor or I can do that in some other ways and what is the best option?
2. Can I do initialization of the handler variable in MainActivity.kt in some other ways and what is a better solution?
3. Any suggestions about application logic would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

MainActivity.kt:

```
package com.logicapp.dox.threadprogressexercise

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.os.Handler
    import android.os.Looper
    import android.os.Message
    import android.view.View
    import com.logicapp.BackgroundThreadClass
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
    
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
        var handler: Handler? = null
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    
            prepareHandlerUI()
    
        }
    
        private fun prepareHandlerUI() {
    
            handler = object : Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
    
                override fun handleMessage(msg: Message?) {
                    if (msg != null) {
                        pb_progress.progress = msg.arg1
                    }
                }
    
            }
    
    
        }
    
    
        fun startThread(view: View) {
    
            if (handler != null) {
                BackgroundThreadClass(handler!!).start()
            }
    
    
        }
    }
```

BackgroundThreadClass.kt:

```
package com.logicapp

import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Message
import android.util.Log

const val TAG = "Thread_back"

class BackgroundThreadClass(val handlerx: Handler) : Thread() {


    override fun run() {

        var message: Message

        for (i in 1..3) {
            message = Message.obtain()
            message.arg1 = i
            handlerx.sendMessage(message)
            Log.d(TAG, "BackgroundThreadClass: " + message)

            sleep(1000)
        }

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_start"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="startThread"
            android:text="Start" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pb_progress"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
            android:max="3" />


    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach is deprecated. You'd better use RxJava2, Kotlin Coroutines or even AsyncTask over this, because you have to be able dispose your background task in order to prevent memory leaks.

Consider the following case, the background thread starts performing some long operation, the activity accidentally gets destroyed due to lack of memory or something else. But the background thread continues dispatching events through the handler and the handler still holds the reference to the destroyed activity and tries to update views in it. See what's wrong?

If you use Observable from RxJava2 (for example), you can dispose the task (with Disposable.dispose() method) in onDestroy callback method.
Also you can emit progress values using Emitter and observe the values through the subscription, so that you don't need to pass a handler instance to the source.

You can check this out here http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/ObservableEmitter.html